# Analyzing dataframes with python for a certain group values to reorganize the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
id; year; methode
1;  2015; 2
2;  2015; 2
3;  2015; 2
12; 2013; 4
4;  2014; 7
1;  2014; 7
3;  2014; 7
```

What would be the best pythonic way to accomplish something like this:

```
id : {counts_of_diffrent_years : sum, years : [hit1,hit2], counts_of_diffrent_methods : 2, methods : [hit1,hit2]}

{3 : {counts_of_diffrent_years : 2, years : [2014,2015], counts_of_diffrent_methods : 2, methods : [2,7]},...}
```

it is not necessary to stay with a nested dict but I thougt it would be be the best way to access the data later. Is there a way doing this with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understand your problem you want

1. to get list of unique values from columns
2. number of unique years and methods

**for first task** use unique() method for your column, for example:

1. df.year.unique() for years
2. df.methode.unique() for methodes

[*check this article*](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_list_unique_values_in_column/) to learn more

**for second task do next:**

1. df.year.value_counts() to count unique count of years
2. df.methode.value_counts() to count unique count of methods

recommend you to get familiar with [*values_count() from pandas documentation*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the unique value shuld only be generated for id's of the same value not for all rows. If the id = 3 is a couple of times in my dataframe i want the years and methods only for this id. And than repeat it for every unique id.

Comment: okey, than I recommend you to use groupby() with condition count > 1. df.groupby('year').filter(lambda x : x['year'].count() > 1), check this article [link](https://pythonforbiologists.com/when-to-use-aggregatefiltertransform-in-pandas/)